# cakephp 2 redirect url with hashtag

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I'm trying to redirect an url containing a hashtag(#) with cakephp's redirect controller function.

When I use this code it url encodes the hashtag

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index',$menuItem."#article_id_".$created_id));

output: http://something.com/link%23article_id_62
```

Is there a way that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the `#` key:

```
$this->redirect([
    // ...
    '#' => 'article_id_' . $created_id,
]);
```

Comment: Hah! Good ole CakePHP. This was a life-saver, driving me crazy.