# How to redirect in CakePHP with # in url, and not %23?

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I am using CakePHP and I am doing this:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view',$id));
```

output in the browser: .../users/view/42

Since I am using JQueryUI tabs, I want the user to be redirected to the tab he just edited, so it should looks something like :

```
 $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view',$id."#groups"));
```

output in the browser: .../users/view/42%23groups

But expected result: .../users/view/42#groups

**Q: How to send a correct url with #id in it to send the focus ?**

*I want, if possible, not use a custom GET param that echo a js in the view.ctp to get the focus asked.*

*I hope it is a CakePHP issue and don't need to change some .htaccess like ([How to rewrite a URL with %23 in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438509/how-to-rewrite-a-url-with-23-in-it))*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the documentation
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $id, '#' => 'groups'));
```

Comment: Just after posted this Q, I found the awnser at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615516/cakephp-2-redirect-url-with-hashtag

In my case it is: 

    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view',$id,'#' =>"groups"));



(*i was searching for '#' in suggested questions title, not 'hashtag', but I have not enought reputation to awnser my own question...*)

Comment: As already mentioned above you would have found the answer reading the official documentation.

Comment: I have the cakephp doc tab pinned, but I don't know why this time I searched first on the web without finding; I came here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it:

```
// Redirect to the home page.
$this->redirect(array(
    'controller' => 'cars',
    'action' => 'index',
    '#' => 'thankyou'
));
```